# My simple API controller action doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I tried to view my API controller action in the browser and I can't seem to find the URL that this endpiont resolves too.  I tried:

```
http://localhost:2797/api/Country/Testing    
http://localhost:2797/api/Country/GetTesting
```

I get this error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>


 public class CountryController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Testing()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
            response.Content = new StringContent("hello", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
            response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
            {
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
            };

            return response;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show us your route configuration inside `WebApiConfig.Register`. If you didn't change the standard route, the correct URI for your controller is just `api/{controller}`, without the `{action}` part.

Answer (score 0):

add `[HttpGet]` on top of `Testing` method

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Testing()
```

or add `Get` at method name

`public HttpResponseMessage GetTesting()`

Then it should be accessible via 
`http://localhost:2797/api/Country/Testing`

Comment: Thanks.  When I do that, chrome asks me to download a file with the content 'hello' in it. why is that? header issue?

Comment: It means that now your method is working, about downloading text file: you content is string content  `new StringContent(`

Comment: remove `response.Content = ..` line totally